# Can we set Suite Name and Test Name during runtime/dynamically using TestNG?

Tags: testng

Here some code,

```
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
   suite.setName("My Suite");
   XmlTest test1 = new XmlTest(suite);
   test1.setName("My Test");
   List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
   classes.add(new XmlClass("com.testng.Testngexmp"));
   test1.setXmlClasses(classes);
 List<XmlTest> myTests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
   myTests.add(test1);

   suite.setTests(myTests);

   List<XmlSuite> suite_a = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
   suite_a.add(suite);
   TestNG tng = new TestNG();
   tng.setXmlSuites(suite_a);
   tng.run();
```

Here, I set suite name as "**My Suite**" and test name as "**My Test**".
My question is that Shall we set SuiteName and TestName during **runtime/dynamically**.

Please suggest me if possible how to set Suite name and Test Name dynamically.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do that and how do you plan to determine the name?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am thinking like,                                             Suppose If I have more than one suite,so                                              1.can I select required suite dynamically with Suite name?                             (OR)                                                                                                        2.Is it mandatory to give suite name as Static even though exist more than one suite?

Comment: You don't answer my questions. Why do you want to run TestNG by code ? You should explain a bit more the whole picture of what you are trying to do.